# File mapping reference from another file

Tags: shell-script

File1.txt

```
age name city
23  ABC  delhi
25  xyz  mumbai
12  xxx  pune 
21  YYY delhi
```

File2.txt

```
city   pincode
delhi  001
mumabi 002
pune   003
```

I need to replace city column in file1 with pincode of `file2`. also duplicate entry should be filed.

```
age name pincode
23  ABC  001
25  xyz  002
12  xxx  003 
21  YYY 001
```

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2}NR>FNR{if($3 in a){print $1,$2,a[$3]}}' file2 file1
age name pincode
23 ABC 001
25 xyz 002
12 xxx 003
21 YYY 001
```

Answer (score 0):

Below `awk` program will help you.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

FILENAME == "file2.txt" {
    if (FNR > 1) {
        city[$1]=$2
    }
}

FILENAME == "file1.txt" {
    if (FNR > 1 ) {
        print($1, $2, city[$3])
        } else {
        print
    }
}
```

When executing the script you have to give the `file2.txt` before `file1.txt` as the mapping has to be built first and then the replacement.

Output

```
$ ./city.awk file2.txt  file1.txt 
age name city
23 ABC 001
25 xyz 002
12 xxx 003
21 YYY 001
```